# How to delete a row from pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I want to delete a row in pivot table, but nothing changes, so can anyone help me on this case? I have pivot table like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('group_list', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('group_id');
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->primary(['group_id','id']);
        });
    }
```

My first model:

```
class AddressBook extends Model
{
    public function addressbookgroups(){
        
        return $this->belongsToMany(AddressBookGroup::class, 'group_list', 'id', 'group_id');
    }
...
}
```

My second model:

```
class AddressBookGroup extends Model
{
      
    public function addressbooks(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AddressBook::class, 'group_list', 'group_id','id');
    }
  
}
```

In index blade I want to delete a row from AddressBook blade:

```
 ....
  <form action="{{ route('group-list.destroy', $addressbook->id) }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     @method('delete')
    <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')"
       class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
   </form>
```

And finally my method for delete:

```
class AddressBookGroupListController extends Controller
{
   public function destroy(AddressBook $address_book)
    {
        $address_book->delete();
        return redirect('address-book-group-list');
    }
}
```

Comment: Read docs : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete an entry from the pivot table, you can do it with the help of relations.

```
$address_book = AddressBook::find($id);
```

Delete entries from pivot table formed from combination of above `$address_book` and the `address_book_group` with the id as `$address_book_group_id`

```
$address_book->addressBookGroups->detach($address_book_group_id);
```

Delete all pivot table entries associated with `$address_book`

```
$address_book->addressBookGroups->detach();
```

Comment: But I don't have $address_book_group_id at pivot table, as you see, this table has just two fields, do you think, I need to add this field: $address_book_group_id

Comment: No, that is just the value. By this `$address_book_group` I meant that this is the value for the `group_id` column in the pivot table

Comment: inside `detach()` you place the value of the other table's key that you've used in the pivot table as foreign key, which in your case is 'group_id'

Comment: But need to delete from Address Book page, because I dont want to delete all group, just a data in this group with id =1 for example

Comment: `I want to delete a row in pivot table`(from your question) You wanted to delete an entry from the pivot table, right?. Deleting from pivot table can be done using `detach` as I mentioned in my answer. Anyways, If you  want to delete AddressBook instance, there maybe entries in the pivot table that might be using it, so you need to remove them first and then delete that AddressBook instance.

Comment: It would be great if you could include an example in the post and the expected result. That way it makes it easier to understand, what does the question demand. And in your example try to  have entries in your pivot table as well.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, in the pivot table I want to delete a row, in my case, an address book, that is also part of AddressBookGroup, but not all group, just that AddressBook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218813/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-triarta-av).